# Web driver get Item From Local Storage

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Here my code:

I am getting null exception

```
     String sItem = getItemFromLocalStorage("value");
     System.out.println(sItem);
    }

    public static String getItemFromLocalStorage(String key)
    {
        return (String) js.executeScript(String.format(
            "return window.localStorage.getItem('adminIdToken');", key));
    }
```

Comment: Could you add a full valid code block and the error stacktrace?
You can have a problem either on the js attribute or the key argument.

Comment: Are you using an Augmenter to access the driver internals?